# angularjs: setting a scope variable from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

First what I want:
I have a series of thumbnails. When I click on one, I want that specific thumbnail to be shown in a bigger div, with its description. (For later: should be animated).

Now I have the directive and the controller, but I don't know how to set the appropriate variable!

So some code:
First HTML: here is the root `.jade` file for this section. I have a directive called `product`.

```
section
    .detail-view(ng-show="vm.showDetail")
      .prod-desc(ng-bind="vm.detailPic")
      .prod-img(ng-bind="vm.detailDesc")
    product.col-xs-12.product_tile(ng-repeat="item in vm.products", item="::item")
```

As you can see, the product directive is part of an `ng-repeat`; for this reason, the div I want to show the resized image is **outside** the iteration (`.detail-view`).

The product directive:

```
'use strict';
ProductDirective.$inject = ['ShopCart', '$animate', 'User'];

function ProductDirective(ShopCart, $animate, User) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        template: require('./product.html'),
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element) {            
        scope.toggleDetails = toggleDetails; 
     }

     function toggleDetails() {
            if (!scope.isSelected && isBlurred()) return;

            scope.vm.detailPic  = scope.item.photo;
            scope.vm.detailDesc = scope.item.prod_description;
            scope.vm.isSelected = !scope.isSelected;
            scope.showDetail = !scope.showDetail;

            var action = scope.isSelected ?
     }
}
```

Now the div I want to update with the image in big is **outside** the iteration - and hence outside the scope of the directive. How can I set the value of `showDetail`, `showDesc` and `showPic`?

As I am using `controllerAs` with value `vm`, I thought I could just do `scope.vm.detailPic = scope.item.photo;`, as in other solutions I have seen that when setting a property on a root object, it would be propagated...but I get

> Cannot set property 'detailPic' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

For now, what works (but looks a bit odd to me) is this, in `toggleDetails()`

```
scope.$parent.$parent.vm.detailPic = scope.item.photo;
scope.$parent.$parent.vm.detailDesc = scope.item.prod_description;
scope.$parent.$parent.vm.showDetail = !scope.$parent.$parent.vm.showDetail
```